# How to write in directory of program?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream

With that code

```
    BufferedReader reader;
    InputStream fis;
    fis = Logs.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I can read from **data** file from **src** folder.
[image]

How can I read it from **config** folder?
And main question **How can I write there?**
Btw

```
getResourceAsStream("../config/data");
```

is not working, if I want to read from config directory.

Comment: First of all, do you know what `getResourceAsStream` does?

Comment: Really - no. I just find it helpful sometime ago, to read some data from jar file of program.

Comment: btw I'd like to write right in JAR file of future program, not on somewhere on hard disk.

Comment: You can't write resources. The JAR file containing the program is read-only. Think of something else.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's not a duplicate of that duplicate but it's certainly a duplicate of many other duplicates.

Comment: How you deploy the software will be different to how you build the software e.g. there won't be a `src` directory.  I suggest you add config to the classpath and use the classpath as normal.